# How to use return values from functor's with boost::thread

Tags: boost, functor

If I have a functor like this...

```
class DoStuff {

  private:

    std::vector < int > numericStuff;

  public:

    explicit DoStuff (const std::vector <int> &newStuff) : numericStuff (newStuff) {};

    int operator () (void) {

       int ProcessedStuff = 0;

       //...Doing stuff

       return ProcessedStuff;

    };

};
```

...now, if I wanted to use it normally all I would have to do is...

```
//...Vector declared and populated somewhere else
DoStuff stuff (Vector);
int someNumber = stuff();
```

...and there you go.  What I want to do is throw it into a boost::thread like this...

```
DoStuff stuff (Vector);
boost::thread (stuff);
```

...and then use it, but for the life of me I can't find out how.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this. To "return a value" from a thread, you have to use [Futures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures).
Quoting from the above documentation:

> When the packaged task is invoked, it invokes the contained function
>   in turn, and populates a future with the return value. **This is an
>   answer to the perennial question: "how do I return a value from a
>   thread?"**: package the function you wish to run as a
>   boost::packaged_task and pass the packaged task to the thread
>   constructor. The future retrieved from the packaged task can then be
>   used to obtain the return value. If the function throws an exception,
>   that is stored in the future in place of the return value.

Comment: I see, thank you.  I'm new to boost, and I didn't catch that when i was reading the thread documentation.  Guess I'd better learn about futures then.